# What is a "REPL" in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, read-eval-print-loop

I saw a reference to creating a "REPL".  What is a REPL?

```
var arDrone = require('ar-drone');
var client  = arDrone.createClient();
client.createRepl();
```

Comment: Open Chrome's developer console and execute a statement like `var x = 'hi';` Then type `x` and the console returns `'hi'` That is a REPL!

Comment: Avoid advice that encourages the use of a REPL. It stands for Real Evil Programming Language and [Typescript is the most evil of all](https://medium.com/@lonniebiz/typescipt-is-just-another-effort-by-anders-hejlsberg-to-statically-type-a-dynamic-world-324e4320e13a).

Comment: There is some debate that only LISP languages _truly_ have a REPL, though many people would beg to differ with that.  See for instance: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5671214/is-lisp-the-only-language-with-repl

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Good information in the [repl](/questions/tagged/repl) tag right here on Stack Overflow:

> About read-eval-print-loop
>
> A Read-Eval-Print Loop (REPL) is an interactive interpreter to a programming language. It originated with LISP systems, but many other languages (Python, Ruby, Haskell, Tcl, etc.) use REPL's to manage interactive sessions. They allow for simple experimentation with a language by bypassing the compile stage of the "code -> compile -> execute" cycle.
>
> There are 4 components to a REPL (named in LISP notation):
>
> - A read function, which reads input from the keyboard
> - An eval function, which evaluates code passed to it
> - A print function, which formats and displays results
> - A loop function, which runs the three previous commands until termination

Comment: That's great. Thanks for making it into a true answer!

Comment: Can I then say that XCode Playground application is a REPL? Or C# Interactive in Visual Studio - is it REPL?

Answer (score 16):

The first Google hit gives you the definition on Wikipedia: REPL stands for [read–eval–print loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop):

> A read–eval–print loop (REPL) is a simple, interactive computer programming environment.

In short, it starts an interactive console where you can type in commands and immediately see the result of these commands.

Comment: Also, [from the documentation of the library](https://github.com/felixge/node-ar-drone#clientcreaterepl): *`client.createREPL()`

Launches an interactive interface with all client methods available in the active scope. Additionally client resolves to the client instance itself.*

Comment: I was surprised also, the question received two downvotes.  Somebody must not like REPLs very much!

Answer (score 1):

If supported by language, REPL is a interactive way of code or command execution.

ftp://ftp.cs.utexas.edu/pub/garbage/cs345/schintro-v14/schintro_114.html