# return vs console.log in javascript

Tags: javascript

This could be simple for all of you but I am still confused here

consider this code

```js
function sum(x,y){
  return x+y
}

function substract(tall , weight){
  return tall - weight
}

sum(3,5)

substract(175 , 75)
```

Now the expected value that I am expecting is **8** and **100** respectively.
However, it only gives me **100**.

Why is that?

Comment: Your call to `sum()` doesn't do anything with the returned value. Same goes for your call to `subtract()`. The purposes of `return` and `console.log()` are completely different.

Comment: The last "value" calculated by your script when it ends is 100.

Comment: @MikeRobinson yes but that's due to the behavior of the console when it evaluates code fragments. Note that the code snippet in the question does not log anything, because it contains no calls to `console.log()` (or any other `console` API).

Comment: @MikeRobinson then why when I do console.log for the same thing it prints out the values I expected? I still didn't get it.

Comment: @TankOne because *that is what `console.log()` is supposed to do*.  The `return` statement has absolutely nothing to do with the browser console.

Comment: @Pointy again sir, you're saying my call to sum doesn't do anything with returned value which is why it didn't print it out but it does for the second one? why is that?

Comment: Click on the "Run code snippet" button above. What do you see?

Comment: [What is a “REPL” in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13603021) + https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop

Comment: @Pointy I see nothing but again How can I actually print out both values respectively in Javascript?

Comment: `console.log(sum(3, 5));` and `console.log(substract(175 , 75));`. That will use the returned value as a parameter to a call to the `console.log()` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To return the values of these calculations through `console.log()`?

I have also added `document.write()` so you can see how the same can be outputted to browser. I must confesses I'm still a little uncertain as to what you are asking.

```js
function sum(x, y) {
  return x+y
}

function substract(tall , weight) {
  return tall - weight
}

console.log(sum(3,5));
document.write('<p>' + sum(3,5) + '</p>');

console.log(substract(175 , 75));
document.write('<p>' + substract(175 , 75) + '</p>');
```

Comment: Be careful with `document.write`. It has its pitfalls. Better stick with `console.log` or (in a browser context) the other `document` methods.