# Difference between Scala REPL and Clojure REPL - compile speed

Tags: scala, clojure, read-eval-print-loop

I tried to run two factorial functions with the same algorithm, one in Scala, the other in Clojure:

```
// Scala:
def factorial(n:Int) = (1 to n).foldLeft(1: BigInt)(_*_)
```

--

```
;; Clojure:
(defn factorial [x]
  (reduce * (range 1N (inc x))))
```

The first time I enter the function to the REPL, the Clojure one evaluates (function definition, not calculating factorial) without any noticeable delay; while the scala one just paused for a short time. (Although very, very short, still noticeable.)

When I apply the function to calculate the factorial, both return the result very fast.

I would like to gain a basic understanding on the REPL. Are there any difference between the two REPL? Is Scala REPL a real REPL?

Answer (score 10):

A REPL has a rather specific meaning. A "True REPL" would be one that fits the following pattern: Read Eval Print Loop. One can build a REPL in clojure in just a few lines:

```
(loop []
  (let [string (read-line)
        data (read-string line)
        result (eval data)]
    (println result)
    (recur)))
```

Here you see the main parts of a true repl. `read-line` reads some text from the console. `read-string` converts that string to data (lists, vectors, numbers, etc.). `eval` evaluates the data returning a result, and `println` prints the result.

Some would argue (and I would agree) that only those systems that follow these four steps qualify to be called a repl. And some would also point out that Scala is not homoiconic, and so cannot truly have a repl.

By homoiconic, I mean that the compiler operates on the same data structures produced by the language's reader and as manipluated by the language's core constructs. For example, this is perfectly valid Clojure code:

```
 (eval (list (symbol "+") 41 1))) ; evals to 42
```

So that's the gist of the debate over "real" REPLs. Only homoiconic languages like lisp (and perhaps prolog?) can have true REPLs. All others should really be named "interactive interpreters".

As far as speed goes. It's probably due to compiler complexity. The Clojure compiler is just around 10k lines of pretty linear code. Single pass, nothing special. The Scala compiler is pretty advanced, supporting things like static typing and multiple passes. Those extra features aren't needed in a language like Clojure, and they do tend to slow a compiler down a bit.

Comment: Hmm.  I would have thought that if a command line interaction involves separate read, evaluation, and print steps, that would be enough for REPL-ness, whether the language is homoiconic or not.  I wouldn't call something an interpreter if it's compiling before executing.  Of course, there all sorts of intermediate cases between "execute one expression at a time, one after another" and "translate and optimize large pieces of code down to some kind of 'machine' language, and then execute".  However, I don't think any of this matters very much!

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5671214/is-lisp-the-only-language-with-repl